# Automating custom QTranslator contexts

Tags: qt, localization, qt4, translation, qml

Qt lupdate and QTranslator group source strings into exclusive contexts.  This means that a translation defined in one context will not be accessible within a different context.

The default context inside C++ is the name of a class that has overridden `QObject::tr()`.  The default context inside declarative QML is the current filename without extension. To override the translation context, one would use `qApp->translate( "context", "source" )` or `qsTranslate( "context", "source" )` in C++ or QML.

I want to be able to use a single common translation context across a large project and I am finding that specifying the translation context with every single translation function is very tedious.  Is there any existing or future Qt translation framework extensions that would simplify this task?  I am looking for something that would be as simple as `tr( "source" )` and `qsTr( "source" )`, but use a system-wide or project-wide default context.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something easier than that. Use qtTrId/qsTrId (Qt/QML) instead of tr/qsTr and add the -idbased parameter to your lrelease calls. ID based translation has no context at all.

Comment: This seems to work well, thanks!  The "ID" can be a complex string with whitespace and some punctuation, but it does not show up in linguist.  Instead one needs to add special `//% "source text"` comments before the `qtTrId()`/`qsTrId()` calls.  ... or write a script to automatically copy the ID string into the source tag. :) Hopefully I won't need contextual separation down the road.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the **Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS()** macro applied to a class definition that acts solely as a context:

```
class CONTEXT_CLASS {
    Q_DECLARE_TR_FUNCTIONS(CONTEXT_CLASS)
};
```

where CONTEXT_CLASS could be as short as you'd like, let's say X (hoping that doesn't conflict with anything else in your code). That would make your tr() statements

```
X::tr("source");
```

Don't try to #define something to shorten X::tr, as that won't get picked up by the translation tool.

Comment: Cool thanks!  This is perfect for the C++ components.  Is there a way to extend this to QML?